# Overriding template for a specific language

Tags: magento2, theme, template, overrides, overriding

I would like to override a template but only for a specific language (`ar_SA`)

The template I want to override is:
`Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

I have tried putting it in the following locations but it didn't work for any of them:

`<VENDOR>/<THEME NAME>/i18n/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

`<VENDOR>/<THEME NAME>/i18n/ar_SA/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

`<VENDOR>/<THEME NAME>/Magento_Catalog/i18n/templates/product/list.phtml`

`<VENDOR>/<THEME NAME>/Magento_Catalog/i18n/ar_SA/templates/product/list.phtml`

`<VENDOR>/<THEME NAME>/web/i18n/ar_SA/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Any other suggestions or possibilities?

(My Magento version is 2.2.6)

Comment: May I ask what you try to achieve? This sounds to me like there might be an easier solution :-)

Comment: @Fabian In English, the products lists pages flow from left to right. But in Arabic they should be from right to left. This is specially important when the last row is not filled up. I tried fixing it using CSS alone, but apparently, I will need to edit the template itself

Comment: Oh wow. I'm a backend guy, so no clue about frontend, but I would have guessed (no offense here!) that there is a html structure which can do both. But I totally understand that changing HTML depending on language make things easier :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a child theme which inherits from your main theme. Add the template you want to override to your child theme.

See [dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html) on Theme Inheritance.

Change theme for your `ar_SA` store view to the child theme you created.